# What did Confucius mean by saying that the 'rectification of names' is the first thing required to rule a state?

Tags: ethics, political-philosophy, chinese-philosophy

In *Analects XII*, a disciple asked Confucius the right principle of government whereupon Confucious said:

> The one thing needed first is the rectification of names.

What did Confucius mean by this?

Comment: To me, he is doing the same thing Plato did. Things must remain fixed. Fixity. Confucius was probably more concerned with tradition than with triangles, nevertheless this is a move to conserve the Form, conserve the Idea, conserve the noun.

Comment: Isn't the reference to *Analects* XIII (specifically XIII.3 instead of XII? (though 12.17 does also treat the subject).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are experts on site to whose opinions I defer but a brief and approximate answer might run as follows:

## The doctrine of the 'rectification of names'

> Language is one of Confucius s primary concerns, since it is so strongly associated with the social and moral order. Confucius s key theory of language is known as
>    the "Rectification of Names."In Book 13 of The Analects, when asked about the first
>    measure to be taken in order to improve the administration, Confucius replied, "It
>    would certainly be to correct language" (159). He further explained why the rectification of names is imperative:
>
> > If language is incorrect, then what is said does not concord with what was meant, what
> >      is to be done cannot be effected. If what is to be done cannot be effected, then rites and
> >      music will not flourish. If rites and music do not flourish, then mutilations and lesser
> >      punishments will go astray. And if mutilations and lesser punishments go astray, then
> >      the people have nowhere to put hand or foot.
> >      Therefore the gentleman uses only such language as is proper for speech, and only
> >      speaks of what it would be proper to carry into effect. The gentleman in what he says leaves nothing to mere chance (159).
>
> Most commentators of this passage do not emphasize the relationship between language and reality, but the relationship between language and action. Every name
>    contains implications for the social relationships of responsibilities and duties.
>    There is an agreement between name and action (the king must act as a "king" should
>    act). This passage indicates one of the most important tenets of Confucius: that is,
>    that individuals should readjust their behavior according to the expectations raised
>    by their "names." The necessity of the rectification of names lies in the supposition
>    that improper names not only misrepresent human relationships, but also have a
>    direct effect upon action and, as a result, lead to social disorder in reality. (Zheng Jie and Fang Jianjun, 'Language and Consciousness: Brecht's Language Strategy and Confucius's "Rectification of Names"', The German Quarterly, Vol. 86, No. 1 (Winter 2013), pp. 72-89: 80-1.)

## The Greek parallel

> Professor Guthrie limits his comparison of Socrates and Confucius to just
>    one point, the "Rectification of Names." This is the doctrine that things in
>    actual fact should be made to accord with the implications attached to them
>    by names. He writes: "To Socrates, as to Confucius, correct language, the
>    rectification of names, was the prerequisite for correct living and even efficient
>    government."[8] Later, Guthrie supports his comparison by quoting from
>    Phaedo 115e, where Socrates says: "You may be sure my dear Cebes that
>    inaccurate language is not only itself a mistake; it implants evil in men's
>    souls." [9] The passage from the Analects which states this doctrine reads, in part,
>
> > If names be not used correctly, then speech gets tied up in knots; and if speech
> >      be so, then business comes to a standstill.... A superior man considers it
> >      necessary that the names he uses may be spoken appropriately, and also that
> >      what he speaks may be carried out appropriately.

(Warren E. Steinkraus, 'Socrates, Confucius, and the Rectification of Names', Philosophy East and West, Vol. 30, No. 2 (Apr., 1980), pp. 261-264: 262.

[8] W. K. C. Guthrie, The Sophists (Cambridge: Cambridge University Press), 1971, p. 276.
[9] W. K. C. Guthrie, Socrates (Cambridge: Cambridge University Press), 1971. "Perhaps the man who came nearest to the aims of Socrates in his search for meanings of words was not a Greek at all... [but] ... Confucius." p. 16.)